# Where to find a bike to hire / buy / borrow in Southern Spain

Tags: spain, bicycles

I am doing a bike trip in Southern Spain near Lorca- it is relatively short and I don't want to take a bike on the plane for it- I was hoping to hire locally. What are the chances of me finding a mountain bike or hiring one around there (or anywhere in Southern Spain Andalucia region).

Comment: Have you tried Google Translate (bicycle hire --> alquiler de bicicletas). Not sure of my Spanish geography but putting this term into Google Maps and centering on Malaga seems to yield some results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rented mountain bikes from www.bikeiberia.com in Spain! They send the bikes to you and you just send them back when you are done. The service and the bikes were excellent.